# How to write unit test for clear all cache using cache manager

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I have a method that evicts all the caches. PFB code for same:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.admin.AdminResponse;

@Service
public class CachingService {
    
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CachingService.class);

    @Autowired
    protected CacheManager cacheManager;
    
    public AdminResponse evictAllCaches() {
        logger.info("Start - Clearing of cache");
        cacheManager.getCacheNames().parallelStream()
          .forEach(cacheName -> cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).clear());
            
        AdminResponse adminResponse = new AdminResponse();
        adminResponse.setMessage("ok");
        logger.info("End - Clearing of cache");
        return adminResponse;
    }
}
```

Below is the unit test I'm trying to write:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import com.admin.AdminResponse;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class CachingServiceTest {
    
    @InjectMocks
    private CachingService testCachingService;

    @Mock
    protected CacheManager cacheManager;
    
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testEvictAllCaches() {
        AdminResponse adminResponse = testCachingService.evictAllCaches();
        assertEquals("ok", adminResponse.getMessage());
    }
    
}
```

I'm unable to understand how to write unit tests for code

```
cacheManager.getCacheNames().parallelStream()
          .forEach(cacheName -> cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).clear());
```

Can someone please help? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can write test code for Cache as follow:

```
@Test
public void testEvictAllCaches() {
      Cache cache = Mockito.mock(Cache.class);
      when(cacheManager.getCacheNames()).thenReturn(List.of("cacheName1", "cacheName2"));
      Mockito.when(cacheManager.getCache(anyString())).thenReturn(cache);
      AdminResponse adminResponse = testCachingService.evictAllCaches();
      assertEquals("ok", adminResponse.getMessage());
     }
```